# How remove all characters after pattern in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

In LibreOffice Calc how can I use Regular Expressions to find and replace every character after a pattern, and remove the pattern itself.

Example:

- 123_2015970_etgn.jpg
- 124_2015971_etgn.png
- 125_2015972_etgn.JPG

Expected result after Find & Replace (remove _etgn and everything after that pattern)

- 123_2015970
- 124_2015971
- 125_2015972

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replace `_etgn.*` with nothing using regular expressions.

*Edit* Now tested as working - note full stop is required.

[image: SU599242 example]

Comment: Would the period (.) need to be escaped in order to find it as a literal? (I'm not at all familiar with LibreOffice).

Answer (score 1):

i know its pretty old but here is a solution to that.
whatever you want to remove before or after a symbol/char you can use the star symbol

```
*<yourcharcter>
```

,to remove everything before this character

```
<your_char>*
```

to remove everthing after it.

**But before doing it you should enable wildcard option.**
[image]